# How to represent a python-print-like dictionary in latex text?

Tags: align

I want to write a python-print-like dictionary in latex as follows:

```
{a1: [l1, l2, ..., ln];  
 a2: [l2, l4, ..., lm];  
  .  
  .  
  .  
  an: [l3, l5, ..., lk] 
}
```

Anyone can offer some help here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

  \begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
    {a1: [l1, l2, ..., ln];
     a2: [l2, l4, ..., lm];
      .
      .
      .
      an: [l3, l5, ..., lk]
    }
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly.